# Custom Audience list or retrieve users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to integrate facebook market-APIs into my application lets say Custom Audience from the documentation I can see the only method to create and remove users, Is there any method where we can get the list of users that were added to the Custom Audience?

On googling about this, I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426776/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-list-of-users-for-a-custom-audience), which states we cant get the users list from the Custom Audience. But this was answered in 2013, Is this limitation still exists?

The code that I am using to create a user in Custom Audience is

```
const adsSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-ads-sdk');

const CustomAudience = adsSdk.CustomAudience;

const accessToken = <accessToken>;
const api = adsSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(accessToken);

const auidence = new CustomAudience(<audience id>);

 const payload={
     payload: {
         schema: 'EXTERN_ID',
         data: ['1234523434#']
     }
 };

auidence.createUser([], payload).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any method where we can get the list of users that were added to the Custom Audience?

**Nope.**

Facebook hashed data. And can't give.

You can save all sent data in Data Base. (Duplicate auditories in u machine).